# strcpy() not working on some strings but not others

Tags: c, arrays, string, input, strcpy

I'm trying to write a simple text adventure program in C. I'm having an issue with strcpy() when trying to set the name/description of each room in the game (see room_setup()). It sets the name/description for every room except for the first two (NO_ROOM and KITCHEN).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define DIRS 4
#define DEBUG 0
#define MAX_INPUT_LENGTH 100

// defines numeric values for each direction
typedef enum {NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST} en_dirs;

// defines numeric values for each room
typedef enum {
    KITCHEN,
    PANTRY,
    HALLWAY_1,
    HALLWAY_2,
    TROLLS_DOMAIN,
    EMPTY_ROOM_1,
    EMPTY_ROOM_2,
    EXIT,
    NO_ROOM
} en_rooms;

// defines numeric values for each item
typedef enum{
    APPLE,
    KEY,
    NO_ITEM
} en_items;

// defines a struct type to store room data
typedef struct room{
    char name[100];
    char desc[100];
    en_dirs around[DIRS];
} Room;

// defines a struct type to store item data
typedef struct items{
    char name[100];
    char desc[100];
} Item;

void str_read(char *s);     // read string from console, point s to it
void str_upper(char *s);    // convert string to upper case
void room_setup(Room *r);   // fill info about rooms into r array
void item_setup(Item *i);   // fill info about items into i array

int main(void){
    char input[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH];
    char *verb, *noun;

    // arrays to store room and item info. NO_**** is always the final element
    // in their respective enums, so the size of the array will never be larger
    // than necessary.
    Room rooms[NO_ROOM];
    Item items[NO_ITEM];

    room_setup(rooms); // fill rooms array with info
    item_setup(items); // fill items array with info

    en_rooms currentRoom = KITCHEN; // set the starting room to the kitchen

    // main game loop
    while(1){

        // print current room name + description
        printf("-- %s --\n", rooms[currentRoom].name);
        printf("%s\n", rooms[currentRoom].desc);

        printf("\n> ");

        // read input and convert it to upper case
        str_read(input);
        str_upper(input);

        if(DEBUG){
            printf("Input: %s\n", input);
            printf("Length: %d\n", strlen(input));
        }

        // split input into two pieces (expects max of two words, for now)
        verb = strtok(input, " ");
        noun = strtok(NULL, " ");

        if(DEBUG){
            printf("Verb: %s\n", verb);
            printf("Noun: %s\n", noun);
        }

        /*
        if(strcmp(input, "NORTH") == 0 && rooms[currentRoom].around[NORTH] != NO_ROOM){
            currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom].around[NORTH];
        }

        */

    }

    return 0;
}

// points s to new string. clears stdin if user has input more than
// MAX_USER_INPUT characters.
void str_read(char *s){
    fgets(s, MAX_INPUT_LENGTH, stdin); // point s to user input from stdin

    // clear extra characters from stdin, if the user has input more than
    // MAX_INPUT_LENGTH characters.
    if(!strchr(s, '\n')){ // newline does not exist
        while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n'); // discard until newline
    }
}

// converts string s to upper case
void str_upper(char *s){
    int i;
    char c;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++){
        s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
}

// fills the array r with info on each room.
void room_setup(Room *r){

    strcpy(r[NO_ROOM].name, "Nothing there.");
    strcpy(r[NO_ROOM].name, "Description");
    r[NO_ROOM].around[NORTH] = NO_ROOM;
    r[NO_ROOM].around[EAST] = NO_ROOM;
    r[NO_ROOM].around[SOUTH] = NO_ROOM;
    r[NO_ROOM].around[WEST] = NO_ROOM;

    strcpy(r[KITCHEN].name, "Kitchen");
    strcpy(r[KITCHEN].desc, "This is the kitchen.");
    r[KITCHEN].around[NORTH] = NO_ROOM;
    r[KITCHEN].around[EAST] = PANTRY;
    r[KITCHEN].around[SOUTH] = NO_ROOM;
    r[KITCHEN].around[WEST] = NO_ROOM;

    strcpy(r[HALLWAY_1].name, "Hallway");
    strcpy(r[HALLWAY_1].desc, "A long hallway.");
    r[HALLWAY_1].around[NORTH] = HALLWAY_2;
    r[HALLWAY_1].around[EAST] = NO_ROOM;
    r[HALLWAY_1].around[SOUTH] = KITCHEN;
    r[HALLWAY_1].around[WEST] = TROLLS_DOMAIN;

    strcpy(r[TROLLS_DOMAIN].name, "Troll's Domain");
    strcpy(r[TROLLS_DOMAIN].desc, "You see a Troll.");
    r[TROLLS_DOMAIN].around[NORTH] = NO_ROOM;
    r[TROLLS_DOMAIN].around[EAST] = HALLWAY_1;
    r[TROLLS_DOMAIN].around[SOUTH] = EMPTY_ROOM_1;
    r[TROLLS_DOMAIN].around[WEST] = NO_ROOM;

    strcpy(r[EMPTY_ROOM_1].name, "Empty Room");
    strcpy(r[EMPTY_ROOM_1].desc , "An empty room. There was no reason to come here.");
    r[EMPTY_ROOM_1].around[NORTH] = TROLLS_DOMAIN;
    r[EMPTY_ROOM_1].around[EAST] = NO_ROOM;
    r[EMPTY_ROOM_1].around[SOUTH] = NO_ROOM;
    r[EMPTY_ROOM_1].around[WEST] = NO_ROOM;

    strcpy(r[HALLWAY_2].name, "Hallway"); //hallway 2
    strcpy(r[HALLWAY_2].desc, "A long hallway.");
    r[HALLWAY_2].around[NORTH] = EXIT;
    r[HALLWAY_2].around[EAST] = EMPTY_ROOM_2;
    r[HALLWAY_2].around[SOUTH] = NO_ROOM;
    r[HALLWAY_2].around[WEST] = NO_ROOM;

    strcpy(r[EMPTY_ROOM_2].name, "Empty Room");
    strcpy(r[EMPTY_ROOM_2].desc , "An empty room.");
    r[EMPTY_ROOM_2].around[NORTH] = NO_ROOM;
    r[EMPTY_ROOM_2].around[EAST] = NO_ROOM;
    r[EMPTY_ROOM_2].around[SOUTH] = NO_ROOM;
    r[EMPTY_ROOM_2].around[WEST] = HALLWAY_2;

    strcpy(r[EXIT].name, "Exit");
    strcpy(r[EXIT].desc, "You win lol");
    r[EXIT].around[NORTH] = NO_ROOM;
    r[EXIT].around[EAST] = NO_ROOM;
    r[EXIT].around[SOUTH] = HALLWAY_2;
    r[EXIT].around[WEST] = NO_ROOM;

}

// fills the array i with info on each item.
void item_setup(Item *i){
    strcpy(i[APPLE].name, "Apple");
    strcpy(i[APPLE].desc, "A bright red apple.");

    strcpy(i[KEY].name, "Key");
    strcpy(i[NO_ITEM].name, "A silver key.");

    strcpy(i[NO_ITEM].name, "");
    strcpy(i[NO_ITEM].desc, "");
}
```

As a simple test, I made currentRoom increment during the while loop, and had this output:

```
--  --


>
--  --


>
-- Hallway --
A long hallway.

>
-- Hallway --
A long hallway.

>
-- Troll's Domain --
You see a Troll.

>
-- Empty Room --
An empty room. There was no reason to come here.

>
-- Empty Room --
An empty room.

>
-- Exit --
You win lol
```

NO_ROOM and KITCHEN haven't had their info copied to the struct it seems. Can anyone help me work out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: "strcpy() not working on some strings but not others" - so it is not working on any string? Or might it be working on strings once you figured out how it works? I just see a wall of code, no [mcve] as required by [ask], along with other information.

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile. The `around` member is of type `en_dirs`, but it holds an `en_rooms`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for pointing that out. Sadly still have the same issue when changed to `en_rooms` though.

Comment: You have many bugs. I'll point out the biggest one in an answer.

Comment: No idea if this is related to your problem, but be aware that a string read with `str_read` has a trailing `\n`. This is because the way `fgets` works.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Not related, but thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insufficient buffer size - off by 1.

```
// Room rooms[NO_ROOM];
Room rooms[NO_ROOM + 1];
```

or better

```
typedef enum {
  KITCHEN,
  PANTRY,
   ...
  NO_ROOM,

  // Insure ROOM_N is 1 greater than all the others.  
  // Putting it last usually does this.
  ROOM_N  
} en_rooms;

Room rooms[ROOM_N];
```

Same with `Item items[NO_ITEM];`

Likely other issues.

Comment: That sorted it, thanks! There are plenty of other issues yes :/

Answer (score 2):

We have this:

```
typedef enum{
    APPLE,     // 0
    KEY,       // 1
    NO_ITEM    // 2
} en_items;
```

Okay, so `NO_ITEM` is 2. Then we have this:

```
Item items[NO_ITEM];
```

Okay, so `items` is an array of two items. Then we have this:

```
strcpy(i[APPLE].name, "Apple");
strcpy(i[APPLE].desc, "A bright red apple.");

strcpy(i[KEY].name, "Key");
strcpy(i[NO_ITEM].name, "A silver key.");

strcpy(i[NO_ITEM].name, "");
strcpy(i[NO_ITEM].desc, "");
```

So we have an array of two items, and we're trying to initialize all three of them. Oops.